# Get source from where the member's access has been inherited in a gitlab repo via python-gitlab module

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

Using python-gitlab module, I am able to get the list of members from a gitlab repo.
Below is the example code for the same -

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gitlab
from utils.secrets import gitlab_token
import csv

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://repo.webengage.com', gitlab_token,
                   api_version=4) 
projects = gl.projects.list(get_all=True)
csv_file = './maintainers_report.csv'

for project in projects:
   contributors = project.members_all.list(get_all=True)
   print(contributors)
```

I also want the source from where their access has been inherited.
[image]